# Flex mobile AIR app: can not see the content at the bottom

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder4.5, flex-mobile, flex4.6

In Flash Builder 4.6 I've created a Flex Mobile AIR Project.

Why is there neither the 2 buttons nor a scroll bar to see?

And why can't I swipe down to see more text and the 2 buttons?

[image]

Here is my complete and simple source code -

The "home view" - **Agreement.mxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        title="HomeView">

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" gap="10" />
    </s:layout>

    <s:Label text="Agreement" width="100%" textAlign="center" />

    <s:Label width="100%">
        <s:text>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tincidunt rutrum felis eu tincidunt. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In auctor erat nec ligula vestibulum porttitor ornare quam facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pretium elementum elit, vitae aliquet turpis facilisis tempus. Curabitur quis mi tellus, placerat bibendum erat. Vestibulum condimentum dolor eu purus fermentum pharetra. Suspendisse potenti. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla tempus aliquam vehicula.

Ut porta commodo interdum. Vestibulum et magna non felis malesuada mollis eu a dolor. Vivamus non diam purus, quis ultricies mi. Maecenas pharetra lorem ac elit tempor bibendum. Fusce gravida, enim et cursus dignissim, augue lectus consequat diam, sit amet laoreet urna eros a nisi. Phasellus id lacinia elit. Nullam pharetra tempor lobortis. Morbi non orci eget tellus consectetur euismod sed in diam. Sed sit amet fringilla massa. Sed quis ligula diam, ut vulputate odio. Donec dapibus diam vel libero tincidunt eu laoreet mauris adipiscing.     </s:text>
    </s:Label>

    <s:Spacer height="100%" />

    <s:HGroup width="100%" gap="10">
        <s:Button label="I do not agree" width="50%" />
        <s:Button label="I agree" width="50%" />
    </s:HGroup>
</s:View>
```

And the app itself - **Test.mxml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ViewNavigatorApplication 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    firstView="views.Agreement">

</s:ViewNavigatorApplication>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        title="HomeView">
    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" gap="10">
            <s:Label text="Agreement" width="100%" textAlign="center" />

            <s:Label width="100%">
                <s:text>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tincidunt rutrum felis eu tincidunt. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In auctor erat nec ligula vestibulum porttitor ornare quam facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pretium elementum elit, vitae aliquet turpis facilisis tempus. Curabitur quis mi tellus, placerat bibendum erat. Vestibulum condimentum dolor eu purus fermentum pharetra. Suspendisse potenti. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla tempus aliquam vehicula.

        Ut porta commodo interdum. Vestibulum et magna non felis malesuada mollis eu a dolor. Vivamus non diam purus, quis ultricies mi. Maecenas pharetra lorem ac elit tempor bibendum. Fusce gravida, enim et cursus dignissim, augue lectus consequat diam, sit amet laoreet urna eros a nisi. Phasellus id lacinia elit. Nullam pharetra tempor lobortis. Morbi non orci eget tellus consectetur euismod sed in diam. Sed sit amet fringilla massa. Sed quis ligula diam, ut vulputate odio. Donec dapibus diam vel libero tincidunt eu laoreet mauris adipiscing.     </s:text>
            </s:Label>

            <s:Spacer height="100%" />

            <s:HGroup width="100%" gap="10">
                <s:Button label="I do not agree" width="50%" />
                <s:Button label="I agree" width="50%" />
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:View>
```

In Flex 4, you need to specify if someone needs to scroll by using the Scroller :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`Scroller`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Scroller.html).

As the [docs note](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html), a [`Label`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Label.html) alone won't provide scrolling:

> Label is the fastest and most lightweight, but is limited in its capabilities: no complex formatting, **no scrolling**, no selection, no editing, and no hyperlinks.

This is inconvenient to wrap anything that might be larger than the display in a `Scroller`, but not impossibly so.

For your case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        title="HomeView">

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" paddingLeft="10" gap="10" />
    </s:layout>

    <s:Label text="Agreement" width="100%" textAlign="center" />
    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:VGroup>
            <s:Label width="100%">
                <s:text>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean tincidunt rutrum felis eu tincidunt. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In auctor erat nec ligula vestibulum porttitor ornare quam facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc pretium elementum elit, vitae aliquet turpis facilisis tempus. Curabitur quis mi tellus, placerat bibendum erat. Vestibulum condimentum dolor eu purus fermentum pharetra. Suspendisse potenti. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla tempus aliquam vehicula.

                Ut porta commodo interdum. Vestibulum et magna non felis malesuada mollis eu a dolor. Vivamus non diam purus, quis ultricies mi. Maecenas pharetra lorem ac elit tempor bibendum. Fusce gravida, enim et cursus dignissim, augue lectus consequat diam, sit amet laoreet urna eros a nisi. Phasellus id lacinia elit. Nullam pharetra tempor lobortis. Morbi non orci eget tellus consectetur euismod sed in diam. Sed sit amet fringilla massa. Sed quis ligula diam, ut vulputate odio. Donec dapibus diam vel libero tincidunt eu laoreet mauris adipiscing.     </s:text>
            </s:Label>

            <s:Spacer height="100%" />

            <s:HGroup width="100%" gap="10">
                <s:Button label="I do not agree" width="50%" />
                <s:Button label="I agree" width="50%" />
            </s:HGroup>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:View>
```

Comment: "Label is the fastest and most lightweight"? Where is the source for that? Both official Adobe documents and presentation logs from MAX conferences in 2010/2011 state that StyleableTextfield is the fastest for mobile applications (directly followed by Label, though).

Comment: Right before that quote are a couple links to the documentation for `Label`, that's the source.

Comment: Ahhh, sorry. Missed that. Still, StyleableTextfield is said to be faster than label, even though the performance difference outside of an ItemRenderer probably won't matter for the majority of applications.